# QT cannot find OpenMP <omh.h>

Tags: c++, qt

I cannot use the openmp library in QT Creator. I am using QT Creator 7.0.2 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

GCC 11.2.0

Similar bug: https://forum.qt.io/topic/122079/qt-creator-4-14-0-cmake-project-with-openmp-omp-h-not-found

Steps to reproduce:
CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(test LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(test main.cpp)

find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
if(OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(test OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
endif()
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error:

```
main.cpp:2:10: 'omp.h' file not found
```

It's clear that gcc has the OpenMP libraries available:

```
cd /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
```

```
ls
```

```
cc1                crtprec80.o        libgomp.a           libstdc++.a
cc1plus            g++-mapper-server  libgomp.so          libstdc++fs.a
collect2           include            libgomp.spec        libstdc++.so
crtbegin.o         libasan.a          libitm.a            libsupc++.a
crtbeginS.o        libasan_preinit.o  libitm.so           libtsan.a
crtbeginT.o        libasan.so         libitm.spec         libtsan_preinit.o
crtend.o           libatomic.a        liblsan.a           libtsan.so
crtendS.o          libatomic.so       liblsan_preinit.o   libubsan.a
crtfastmath.o      libbacktrace.a     liblsan.so          libubsan.so
crtoffloadbegin.o  libcc1.so          liblto_plugin.so    lto1
crtoffloadend.o    libgcc.a           libquadmath.a       lto-wrapper
crtoffloadtable.o  libgcc_eh.a        libquadmath.so      plugin
crtprec32.o        libgcc_s.so        libsanitizer.spec
crtprec64.o        libgcov.a          libssp_nonshared.a
```

Comment: You can put an else() in your CMakeLists.txt file and see if cmake is able to find openmp package.

Comment: 1. This is not about Qt creator and maybe not even about Qt.
2. This is about CMake. Was that *dev* library installed?

sudo dpkg -l | grep -i omp | grep dev
https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/libopenmpi-dev